# How do I stop auto slide of Bootstrap carousel?

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to build a carousel that will only slide if the previous or next button is clicked.

At the moment, it does not move until I click it, but its sliding automatically every few seconds.

```
<div id="story-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
```

I tried using `data-interval="false"` but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure, when i change that `data-bs-interval` to `false`, it doesn't work also, but when i change `data-bs-ride="carousel"` to `data-bs-interval="false"` (i remove that `data-bs-ride`). It worked

Comment: Crazy! This also worked for me. As soon as I set `data-bs-interval` to `false`, it starts scrolling uncontrollably. But after removing `data-bs-ride="carousel"` while keeping `data-bs-interval` as `false`, it worked.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The option to prevent auto sliding is `data-bs-interval` not `data-interval`

Setting that to `false` will stop the auto sliding.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/carousel/#options

Comment: Doesn't work. When I set `data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-interval="false"` the carousel autoplays and without any delay (as if interval was zero).

Comment: From their docs "If set to 'carousel', autoplays the carousel on load"

Comment: Sure, but if I remove "carousel" it doesn't even change slide when clicking the buttons or swiping.